# How to model a plastic food tray?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and would like model a plastic food tray.
Which is the best way to model it ?[image]

Comment: mesh cube and mesh cone, add modifier boolean operation union

Answer (score 2):

Try to model only one half of the object, then enable the ***Mirror Modifier*** and check the ***X*** and ***Y*** boxes under *Axis* option (remember to have the origin point placed as pictured below). Apply the modifier when you're done with modeling. You may then add the *Subsurf* and *Solidify* Modifiers.

[image]

You can easily model the curved corners of a tray using the [***Spin*** tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html). To make the ribs, divide the surface using *Loop Cut* tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Select one face, press <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it a bit.
[image]

Now select the next face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the earlier operation. Do it with all the faces.
[image]

Select all faces and extrude them (<kbd>E</kbd>)
[image]

You may scale them horizontally for better effect. Scale one, click the next one and use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to speed up the process.
[image]

Use a *Loop Cut* tool again to make the edges of the ribs sharper.
[image]

Comment: mirroring is the last part. How did you come to the first part ? Are these surfaces ? How do I make the ribs in de side wall ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check it out :).

Comment: @Gonzou instead of repeatedly extruding and scaling the faces one by one, and then extruding again, you can do it in a single operation insetting all them using *individual faces*. http://i.stack.imgur.com/EJMhz.gif

Comment: @cegaton thanks for a nice trick! Haven't heard about it before. It is never late to learn :).