# How to make a food tray

Tags: modeling

How can I go about modeling a tray like this?
[image: example image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34372/how-to-model-a-plastic-food-tray

Answer (score 5):

1. Start with a cube, go into edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and scale it (<kbd>S</kbd>) to approximately the proportions you want.
2. Select and delete the top face (<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>).
3. Go into *Edge Select* mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and select the bottom edge and 4 corners and bevel them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, using the mouse wheel to control the number of cuts.
   [image]
4. Select the top edge and extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) it a couple of times to create the upper lip.
   [image]
5. Add a *Solidify* modifier to give the tray some thickness, and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth it out.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for my delay,